# How do i insert data to SQLite database at the beginning of the Table?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm new in SQLite android developing. I want to save my data using SQLite. I also did that easily extending **SQLiteOpenHelper** class. I used auto-increment key ID on the table. After insert data to the Table when I print all data using **Cursor.moveToFirst()** to **Cursor.moveToLast()** (not using any ordered by command) I found that the data are printing in the insertion order (Or, based on key ID ascending order).

Well, that is good! But the problem is that I also need to append data at the beginning of the same table (or Print the newly inserted data first before the old data).

I searched internet but I didn't find any solution. How can I do that?

Help me to describe the functions:

> **insertDataToTheBiggening(String data)**
>
> **insertDataToTheEnd(String data)**

My code is:

```
public class StoreData extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;


private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "AllData";

private static final String TABLE = "Data";


private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_NAME = "versity_name";
private static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
private static final String KEY_INFO = "info";
private static final String KEY_DATE = "date";
private static final String KEY_LINK = "link";


public StoreData(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

public StoreData(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, name, factory, version);
}

public StoreData(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version, DatabaseErrorHandler errorHandler) {
    super(context, name, factory, version, errorHandler);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE + "("
            + KEY_ID +  " integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + KEY_NAME + " text not null, "
            + KEY_TITLE + " text not null, "
            + KEY_INFO +  " text not null, "
            + KEY_DATE +  " text not null, "
            + KEY_LINK +  " text not null"
            + ")";
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE);


    onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
}

public void addNewData(String VersityName, String Title, String Info, String Time, String Link)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, VersityName);
    values.put(KEY_TITLE, Title);
    values.put(KEY_INFO, Info);
    values.put(KEY_DATE, Time);
    values.put(KEY_LINK, Link);



    db.insert(TABLE, null, values);
    db.close(); 
}


}
public void PrintAllData()
{
    new AsyncTask<String, String, String>() {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

            SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

            String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE ;

            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
            try{
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

                    do{
                        publishProgress(cursor.getString(0)+" "+cursor.getString(1),cursor.getString(2),cursor.getString(3),cursor.getString(4),cursor.getString(5));
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    }while (cursor.moveToNext());
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally{
                db.close();
                cursor.close();
            }


            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... strings)
        {

            ManagePanes.addPane(strings[0],strings[1],strings[2],strings[3],strings[4]);
        }
    }.execute("");
}
```

Comment: You dont need to add data at beginning, u just need to order in decreasing ids

Comment: You need to order your data while retrieving *SELECT * FROM TABLE ORDER BY id DESC*

Comment: but the old data sequence will be change, I just want to append data at the begging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I found that the data are printing in the insertion order

You may have observed this happening, but there is no guarantee that this will always be the case.  In general SQL tables are modeled after unordered sets of records, that is to say there is no internal order to the records of any table.  So the solution to your problem is to just do normal SQLite inserts into your table, and if you want an order, then use one or more columns to impose that order via an `ORDER BY` clause.  For example, you could have a timestamp column which can represent an early or late record, and to query out records in the order you want.

Comment: thanks, but how do i order by my id.  It will helpful if you give me the code

Comment: and using order by is efficient?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM yourTable ORDER BY some_id ASC/DESC` ?  I don't really understand your question.  I tried to clarify a misconception you have about SQLite.  You don't insert into the "beginning" or "end" of a table, rather just do an insert.  If you want a specific order, then use `ORDER BY`.

Comment: is it efficient?

Comment: Efficiency is a totally different story.  If you use `ORDER BY` on a column which has an _index_, then yes it can be very fast.  Although, at the same time if you have many indices then insertion might slow down if part or all of the index needs to be rebuilt.  It is a trade off.

Comment: what is index? how do I use It or Define It?

Comment: @user8249578 If you really have never worked with indices in SQL at all before, then you might want to [start with a good tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_indexes.htm) and then come back here when you have a more focused question.

Answer (score 0):

Give *negative* id for insert in beginning and *increment positive* id and add values for insert at ending

At time of describe table using id
Min-negative to Max-positive

Comment: I also thought like that...but how do i implement it, as i'm new in android please give me the code.

Comment: This answer is slightly wrong, in that it speaks of the beginning and ending during an insert.  In general, inserting a record with a low value of a certain column does not mean that it goes to the "beginning" of a table.

Comment: Just remove 'auto increment' for id and give id value at insertion time.

You have to store your old min-id and max-id value for new insetion id